# Migrating to Scoped Storage for Android Q

Tags: android

When a user takes a photo in my app the image gets saved locally in the internal storage. I also allow then to be moved to the external storage where they can grab then by plugging the device into a computer and getting them off of there if they want.

I would do that by doing this

```
val tempDir = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "My_App_Folder")

val baseFile = File(filePath)
if(baseFile.exists()){
    val targetFile = File(directory.path+File.separator+targetFileName)
    baseFile.copyTo(targetFile)
    baseFile.delete()
}
```

Image would end up in `Pictures/My_App_Folder` like I want

Now trying to move to `MediaStore` to support the `scoped storage` I am not sure how to save the file to the same folder.

I tried doing

```
val values:ContentValues = ContentValues()
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpg")
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, targetFileName)
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, targetFileName)
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
   values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,System.currentTimeMillis())
   values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/My_App_Folder")
   uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL),values)
}else{
   uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values)
}
```

But nothing appears in that folder now, I feel like I am missing something fundamental with MediaStore and I am not sure what it is

Comment: You're not actually saving the image there. I've not tested the scoped storage stuff on Q yet, but I'm pretty sure you just need to `ContentResolver#openOutputStream()` with that returned `uri`, and write your `baseFile` to that.

Comment: ah ok let me try that

Comment: @MikeM. yup that was it thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mike pointed out I have to save the image using the output stream from the uri after inserting into the content resolver so a working backwards compatible example looks like this.

```
private fun saveFileToExternalStorage(directory:File?,filePath:String,targetFileName:String){
        var uri:Uri? = null
        val values:ContentValues = ContentValues()
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpg")
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, targetFileName)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, targetFileName)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,System.currentTimeMillis())
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/My_App_Folder")
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
            uri= contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY),values)
        }

        val baseFile = File(filePath)
        if(baseFile.exists()){

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                directory?.let {
                    val targetFile = File(it.path+File.separator+targetFileName)
                    baseFile.copyTo(targetFile)
                }
            }else{
                uri?.let {
                    val outputStream: OutputStream? = contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)
                    outputStream?.let{
                        val inputStream: InputStream = File(filePath).inputStream()
                        inputStream.copyTo(outputStream,1024)
                    }
                    values.clear()
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
                    contentResolver.update(uri,values,null,null)
                }
            }

            baseFile.delete()
        }
    }
```

Comment: why MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY). why not MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI ?

Comment: @tyczj How to do this in java for PDF file ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63480192/how-to-save-and-store-pdf-file-in-a-folder-using-scoped-storage-in-android-10-an