# Trying to save a pdf file in device storage for android 10 and above

Tags: java, android, pdf, save

[image: code]

Need to make this code work in devices having version android 10 and above.
What do I need to enter in myPdfDocument.writeTo() method to make this work.

Comment: please include code as text - we cant copy what you've provided

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63480192/how-to-save-pdf-file-in-a-media-store-in-android-10-and-above-using-java